# Get String of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a plist with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>2075</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dublin-Pony-kids-25_thumb</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>1558</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>2219</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dublin-Pony-kids-26_thumb</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>1751</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>2532</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dublin-Pony-kids-27_thumb</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>1732</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>height</key>
        <real>2430</real>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dublin-Pony-kids-28_thumb</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <real>1730</real>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I wonder how to get a NSString with all results for key->name.
I would like to have somthing like Dublin-Pony-kids-25_thumb, Dublin-Pony-kids-26_thumb, Dublin-Pony-kids-27_thumb, Dublin-Pony-kids-28_thumb.

I can read it like `(NSString *)imageNameAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {` 
but this only returns one value. I want all values of the key->name as a `NSString`.

I`new to this so please some help.

Answer (score 2):

If you load the plist into an array (via `+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...]`), then you should be able to do:

```
NSArray *plistContents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...]; //load the plist into memory
NSArray *names = [plistContents valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you answer. It gave me the right way. I'm calling my thumbs like this know.

```
- (NSArray *)thumbNames {
//For the thumbs we need a different array than for the images
//Load the plist
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistContents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; //load the plist into memory
NSArray *thumbNames = [plistContents valueForKey:@"name"];


return thumbNames;
```

}

The var thumbNames I can now load into a new view.

Cheers

Dirk